# My Semantic-UI modules appear to be non-functional

Tags: semantic-ui

I am new to Semantic-UI and am having trouble with getting any modules to work; other Semantic-UI elements seem to be working (e.g. button animations). But for some reason none of the modules seem to be functioning properly. Specifically I have been try to set up tabs on a page, the tabs are clickable, but all the content of ALL the tabs is being displayed below when it should be hidden (except for the clicked tab ofcourse). I'm running Semantic UI with node js v10.1.0 and jquery 3.1.1., editing and opening with Visual Studio Code. I have followed the set up of Semantic as per their website.

I have tried different modules (e.g. accordion, dropdown) but none of the others seem to function properly either. I'm just trying to run the code from the website to no avail. I have tried reinstalling semantic ui, which did not seem to fix it. (I do note that whenever I have installed semantic ui there always appear to be warnings about deprecated packages/files but everything still installs).

HTML:

```html
<div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
  <a class="item active" data-tab="first">First</a>
  <a class="item" data-tab="second">Second</a>
  <a class="item" data-tab="third">Third</a>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment active" data-tab="first">
  First
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="second">
  Second
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="third">
  Third
</div>
```

JS:

```js
$('.menu .item').tab();
```

None of the tabs function as tabs. All content is displayed that should be hidden by tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. It appears the css files from the saved semantic-ui files were not being detected through my href statements; it was fixed by changing the href tags linking to the files to instead link to the cloudflare links.